# Changing the properties of an element from a separate React Native View

Tags: react-native

Given the following App.tsx:

```
function App() {
   return (
      <View>
         <View>
            displayText();
         </View>
         <View>
            displayPressable();
         </View>
      </View>
   )
}

function displayText() {
   return (
     <Text ... properties of text element need to change when Pressable is pressed />
   )
}

function displayPressable() {
   const handlePress = (evt: GestureResponderEvent) => {  
      // code must manipulate properties of Text element returned from displayText()
   }
   return (
      <Pressable onPress={(evt) => handlePress(evt)}> 
   )
}
```

What is the correct way to change the properties of the `Text` element when the `Pressable` element is pressed?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `state` in a parent and then pass it down to children via props. Something like this:

```
function App() {
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false)

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <DisplayText isExpanded={isExpanded}/>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Toggle value={isExpanded} onChange={setExpanded}/>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

See [Sharing State Between Components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) for details.